# SQL Server : List all values from tableA for each values in tableB

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to select and then insert tableA's values for each values of tableB. Any suggestions?

So basically the result table will be something like this:

```
1 | 1 
1 | 2 
1 | 3 
2 | 1 
2 | 2 
2 | 3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a `cross join`:

```
select a.col1, b.col1
from a cross join
     b
order by a.col1, b.col1;
```

You can create  a new table using the `into` clause.  Or create the new table first and use `insert into`.

Comment: Thank you. Helped a lot.